# C# add scheme to URI

Tags: c#, uri

I'm trying to add the HTTP Protocol to this URI "example:8888"

What I've done :

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("example:8888")
{
  Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
};
var uri = uriBuilder.Uri;
```

The Output is

```
http:0.0.34.184
```

What I'm doing wrong :S ?

Comment: It's `http://0.0.34.184/` for me, which makes sense [when you](http://superuser.com/q/736583/252526) understand [that format](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/decimalCalcResult?ipAddress=0.0.34.184)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is being parsed as the URL path, not a hostname.
To force it to parse as a hostname, you need to add a scheme to the string.